# File Upload failing using flask

Tags: python, file, flask, save, werkzeug

I was following the exact tutorial for uploading files in Flask, found here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/. 
The code is as follows:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/my/file/path/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
       filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit a empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                filename=filename))
    return '''
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload new File</title>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
  <p><input type=file name=file>
     <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
'''
```

The weird thing is that this worked earlier, extremely well. I even had it hosted on Heroku, and I could upload files just fine. But now, i get the following error:

```
2018-07-26T17:28:36.126457+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2725, in save
2018-07-26T17:28:36.126455+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app2.py", line 33, in upload_file
2018-07-26T17:28:36.126457+00:00 app[web.1]: file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
2018-07-26T17:28:36.126460+00:00 app[web.1]: dst = open(dst, 'wb')
2018-07-26T17:28:36.126515+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my/file/path/uploads/file.png'
```

Does anyone have a guess as to why this is happening? It used to work just fine, but now even the code provided by the Flask developers themselves won't work. I checked the filepath a lot, so I know the issue isn't there, and tested os.path.join on its own, and it worked perfectly. There seems to be an issue with it not saving, specifically file.save itself. But beyond the problem with file.save, I can't figure out what's wrong. **I am still running this on Heroku. It seems that even if I upload a file and try and continue the code, Heroku can't find files/access my directories?**

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: It turns out that anytime I try to access a file in a python (3) script, it fails. But when I run the exact same code, filepaths and all, it works just fine in the python3 executor, which I open from the `python3` command.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem in my loclhost, after I did a conda update --all.  It was all working fine until I did the update.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a heroku issue - heroku files are saved remotely, and I can access those files by running a `heroku run bash`. Doing an ls reveals an entirely different filepath. Fixing everything to match THAT filepath, not the filepaths native to my server, fixed it!